# MySql LOAD DATA with subquery performance issue

Tags: mysql, subquery, load

I'm migrating data into a MySql (5.7.26) database (32GB ram), running as a managed service on AWS. While importing the data, I need to map one of the columns of the CSV being imported to another value using a MEMORY table lookup; so my LOAD DATA resembles the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE table_1(col_1, @var1)
SET col_2 = (select mapped_value from table_2 where id = @var1)
```

table_2 is a 2-column (id, mapped_value) MEMORY table with 3.4MM rows.

When I import the CSV *without* the subquery, I get several million inserts per minute. However, when I run the same import with the subquery the LOAD DATA performance degrades to near zero (~100 inserts per minute). Is this to be expected with a subquery, or is there something I'm doing wrong in the example above?

Comment: Do have index on table_2.id column ? How much time your inner query takes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without the subquery ... several million inserts per minute ... with the subquery ... ~100 inserts per minute

Of course. Server executes the subquery per each separate imported record!

---

Specify datatypes for `table_1.col2` and `table2.id`.

If `table2.id` can be stored into `table_1.col2` then perform 2-step importing:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE table_1(col_1, col_2);
```

```
UPDATE table_1, table_2
SET table_1.col2 = table_2.mapped_value
WHERE table_2.id = table_1.col2;
```

---

If the types are not compatible then I'd recommend to import the data into temporary table and then copy the data into working table with needed substitution. Anycase it will more fast then one-step import with subquery.

Comment: Yes - I'm just surprised that a memory-table lookup on a primary key has such a large cost. Event if that lookup cost 1/10 of a second, I'd expect to see 10/s, 600 / minute. It's not even getting that. I suspect the fact that I'm hitting a 3.4MM row table has something to do with it. 

At any rate, I'll try your suggestion to perform the LOAD into a temporary (MEMORY) table, and perform a `insert ... from select` on that temp table into the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the fact that `memory` tables by default use a hash index instead of a btree index. Read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

Or maybe you don't use an index at all in your `memory` table?

A pretty similar performance problem is described in this blog post: [Performance gotcha of MySQL memory tables](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/02/01/performance-gotcha-of-mysql-memory-tables/)

If you don't have an index on the `id` column, add one (btree!)

> The MEMORY storage engine supports both HASH and BTREE indexes. You can specify one or the other for a given index by adding a USING clause as shown here:
>
> ```
>    CREATE TABLE lookup
>        (id INT, INDEX USING HASH (id))
>        ENGINE = MEMORY;
>    CREATE TABLE lookup
>        (id INT, INDEX USING BTREE (id))
>        ENGINE = MEMORY;
> ```

If you already have an index on that column, check with

```
show indexes from table_2;
```

of what index_type your index is. Convert to btree if necessary.

Comment: Yes, the table I created had a primary key on the `id` column, and unfortunately it appears that neither hash/btree makes a difference.